# Count Of Distinct Records In SQL Where a Distinct Record does not exist

Tags: sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
HOUR    COUNT
0       3
1       3
2       6
4       2
5       1
7       4
8       3
9       6
10      11  
... 
23      3
```

I need the data to look like this:

```
HOUR    COUNT
0       3
1       3
2       6
3       0
4       2
5       1
6       0
7       4
8       3
9       6
10      11
... 
23      3
```

When there is no distinct record of anything happening at a certain hour (ie hour `2` or `6`) I want SQL to insert that hour with a count of 0.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
-- Columns selected
SELECT DISTINCT col1 AS 'HOUR', COUNT(col1) AS 'COUNT'

-- Database Used: DB
FROM DB

-- Filters
WHERE date_col BETWEEN '1/1/13' AND '1/2/13'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1

--*********************************************************************************
-- End Report
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without telling us what DB that you're using because a) you need a numbers table and b) no two databases have the same implementation for that

Comment: Fyi, the sample data was truncated for improved readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to create all the hours:

```
WITH [Hours]([Hour])
AS
(
  SELECT 0 AS [Hour]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Hours].[Hour] + 1 AS [Hour]
  FROM [Hours]
  WHERE [Hours].[Hour] < 23
)

SELECT * FROM [Hours]
```

Then you can use these hours to join on your query:

```
WITH [Hours]([Hour])
AS
(
  SELECT 0 AS [Hour] --Don't forget 0, else you miss one hour on your day!
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Hours].[Hour] + 1 AS [Hour]
  FROM [Hours]
  WHERE [Hours].[Hour] < 23
)

SELECT 
 [Hours].[Hour],
 COUNT([table].[col1]) AS [Count]
FROM [Hours]
LEFT JOIN [table] ON [Hours].[Hour] = [table].[col1]
WHERE [table].[date_col] BETWEEN '1/1/13' AND '1/2/13'
ORDER BY [Hour] ASC
```

Comment: And this solution assumes SQL-Server

Comment: Yes, the link is for SQL Server. But they are available in PostgreSQL (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html) and Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) too. MySQL does not support them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a table of hours, then you can use the query below. Depending on your platform, you may be able to use a function in place of the `CASE`.

```
SELECT a.hour, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.count IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE b.count 
       END AS 'count' 
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS 'hour' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 7 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 8 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 9 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 10 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 11 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 12 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 13 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 14 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 15 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 16 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 17 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 18 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 19 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 20 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 21 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 22 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 23) a 
       LEFT JOIN tbl b 
              ON b.hour = a.hour
```

**Result**

```
| HOUR | COUNT |
----------------
|    1 |     3 |
|    2 |     6 |
|    3 |     0 |
|    4 |     2 |
|    5 |     1 |
|    6 |     0 |
|    7 |     4 |
|    8 |     3 |
|    9 |     6 |
|   10 |    11 |
|   11 |    10 |
|   12 |    11 |
|   13 |     5 |
|   14 |     7 |
|   15 |    10 |
|   16 |     7 |
|   17 |     6 |
|   18 |     8 |
|   19 |     2 |
|   20 |     7 |
|   21 |     5 |
|   22 |     6 |
|   23 |     3 |
```

Comment: probably the closest thing to a cross platform solution except that `SELECT 1 AS 'hour' ` doesn't work on Oracle. That said it could be eaiser for a given Database. For example in SQL Server you could use spt_values or in oracle I would use CONNECT BY LEVEL

Answer (score 0):

You need a case statement:

```
case count(col1)  as 'Count'  
    when null  
    THEN 0  
    ELSE 'Count'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler query to get 24 hours - this is only to build hours table if needed. Use of Sysdate is optional:

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(SYSDATE), 'hh24')-1 + LEVEL "24_hrs"
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;
```

Comment: Minor note, this solution assumes Oracle

Comment: True. I was hoping smth similar to Level exists in Microsoft and MySQL.